# Static enums in Vala?

Tags: enums, vala

I have this snippet:

```
public class Item : Object, ContentItem {
    public static enum State {
        STOPPED,
        RUNNING,
        PAUSED
    }
    ...
}
```

and I get:

```
error: syntax error, expected `enum'
   24 |     public static enum State {
      |            ^~~~~~
```

Is there a way to get class static enums? Obviously it wouldn't make sense to have something like enums copied for every instance of `Item`.

Comment: It's not like the enum is really being copied into each instance. Check the generated code, it should just be an enum in C and some boilerplate to register it with GType.

Comment: @nemequ Thanks! That explains it. Go ahead and write this as an answer if you want.